# Calculate total impedance in circuit with series RL in parallel with C and R

Tags: resistors, impedance, conductors

[image][image]

Hi im trying to find the total impedance in this circuit but im having troubles figuring it out. I have calculated the individual impedance for each branch like following:
Xc = 46.8 ohm at -90 degrees
Xl = 46.8 ohm at 90 degrees

ZR = 1000 + j0

Zc = 0 - j46.8

ZRsL = 10 + j46.8 => (47.8 ∠ 77.93)

So now when i try to find the total impedance the first thing i tried was ZT = 1/((1/ZR)+(1/Zc)+(1/ZRsL)) which i get to be 23.1 ohm. Which is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: So i get how do do it from the comments below but i dont know what numbers to use. Like with (ZT=(Z1⋅Z2⋅Z3)/(Z1⋅Z2+Z1⋅Z3+Z2⋅Z3)) What do i actually put as Z1, Z2 etc. I cant take (10 + j46.8)*( 0 - j46.8) can i? In my mind that is 56.8*-46.8. I know it isnt but i cant figure out how to do it

Comment: Better show the calculations so we can see where the error is. A photo of a neat hand-written attempt will do or you can use MathJAX to format it in the markup.

Comment: Ok, ill see what i can do!

Comment: Ok calculations have been added for ZT

Comment: Your setup is correct, so how are you doing the actual impedance calculation (complex numbers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an earlier version of your question suggested that you may have an answer, just not a process for finding it. If so, you might have posted it up.

Ignoring the voltage source, except for the frequency, I get about the same figures you do for each branch:

1. \$1000 \Omega = 1000 \angle 0^{\circ}\$
2. \$10 \Omega + 14.9mH = 10 + j46.8097305 = 47.8659678 \angle 77.9411244^{\circ}\$
3. \$6.8\mu F = -j46.8102774 = 46.8102774 \angle -90^{\circ}\$

Putting those in parallel, leads to something like:

\$1000\Omega \vert\vert (10\Omega + 14.9mH ) \vert \vert 6.8\mu F = 180.943269 - j31.4410821\$

or,

\$183.654589 \angle -9.85741212^{\circ}\$

I'm just not sure how you got your figure. Do you know if I got my calculations right, though, according to what you were told? I'm reasonably confident about my figure here. But I make mistakes, too.

EDIT: I just used the same thing you referred to:

\$Z_T = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{Z_1} + \frac{1}{Z_2} + \frac{1}{Z_3}} = \frac{Z_1 \cdot Z_2 \cdot Z_3}{Z_1 \cdot Z_2 + Z_1 \cdot Z_3 + Z_2 \cdot Z_3}\$

I used the complex number notation, because it's easier for me. But the above is just the same as:

\$Z_T = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1000} + \frac{1}{10 + j46.8097305} + \frac{1}{-j46.8102774}}\$

EDIT AGAIN: Note to @Joo223: If you want to test out either form of the equation I mentioned, then you MUST keep the fully cartesian equivalent. This means keeping your \$\sqrt{-1}\$ terms separated out. Remember, these are complex numbers and you are using a complex number system. Not the real number system. When you compute Z for something, you get a complex value. The imaginary part might be 0. The real part might be zero. But you still can't just go around thinking that an imaginary part is really just a real part. It's not. You will need a complex number calculator.

So look at these expressions:

\$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1000}+\frac{1}{10 + 46.8097305 i}+\frac{1}{-46.8102774 i}}\$

or, equivalently,

\$\frac{1000 \cdot (10 + 46.8097305 i) \cdot (-46.8102774 i)}{1000 \cdot (10 + 46.8097305 i) + 1000 \cdot (-46.8102774 i) + (10 + 46.8097305 i) \cdot (-46.8102774 i)}\$

Please take *careful note* that I've not just ignorantly stuffed a real numbered value as an \$\Omega\$ value. I've had to keep track of both real and imaginary terms. You will need to use complex number calculations here.

Real numbers do not form a closed algebra over their operations. Complex numbers do close the algebra. But more importantly for electronics is the idea that multiplication by *i* rotates a plot by \$90^{\circ}\$. Or, you might look up Euler's: \$ e^{i \cdot \theta} = cos(\theta) + i\cdot sin(\theta)\$. Investigate the infinite series for e, sine, cosine, and the hyperbolic sine and cosine. It may help, too.

But the point is that you *must* keep things straight in your calculations. I have a complex number calculator that handles everything smoothly for me. So I use it. I can set up the \$\omega = 2\cdot\pi\cdot f\$, as well, and just slap that in along the way. In fact, my calculator allows me to simply type this into it: \$1000 \vert (10 + 14.9mH ) \vert 6.8\mu F\$ and to get the right answer without any further ado. It knows about H and it knows about F and it knows about SI. It knows that + means *in series* and that | means *in parallel*. So it's really easy for me to make sure I'm getting the right results. (I created that calculator software for exactly these reasons.)

Comment: Your math is correct, but I believe OP has this and looking for process.

Comment: Well, I'd prefer the OP to lay out his own procedure first. I honestly don't know what he did. Easier for me to point out a mistake and explain it, than to walk a process in some unknown level of required detail. Seeing his work would guide me, directly.

Comment: Hence my comment to OP question above.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! The correct answer is indeed 183.65 ohm. So now when i calculate this how do i do it? Do i do (46.8*47.9*1000)/((46.8*47.9)+(46.8*1000)+(47.9*1000))

Comment: You cannot do that with complex numbers! In that way you are completely neglecting a complex impedance, i.e., you are neglecting the complex number argument (angle). If you want to do it like that, then you have to write every (complex) number in the cartesian form as follows: \$a+jb\$. E.g., \$1+j\$ (cartesian) is same as \$\sqrt{2}\angle 45^\circ\$ (polar), because \$\sqrt{1^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{2}\$ and \$\arctan\frac{1}{1}=45^\circ\$. Having this in mind, you get something like this \$(1000+j0)(10+j46.8)(0-j46.8)/(...)\$

Comment: @Marko: I generally don't use polar, at all. I keep it entirely as cartesian, knowing that there is always a polar equivalent. I've never had any trouble getting the right results using cartesian and then at the last step converting that to polar, if that's what is required. The two are mathematically equivalent. Note that my answer is correct.

Comment: @Jon223: I'll add a note to my answer to help you out on your question.

Comment: @jonk Of course, your explanation is correct. I was referring to Joo223's "comment-question". It is much easier to do addition/subtraction in Cartesian form, whereas polar form is more suitable for multiplication/division of complex numbers. Both would produce same results, but not in the way Joo223 have described :)

Comment: @marko: Okay. Sorry I misunderstood you, earlier. I've extended my explanation a bit to help Joo223.

Comment: Ah thank you so much for the explanation. Sadly we arent allowed to use calculators that handle complex numbers during exams so i will have to do it in my head. I will try more tomorrow.

Comment: @Joo223: Sorry to hear that. I usually just collect terms in the numerator and denominator to create one complex value above, and one below. Then multiply by 1 formed as a fraction of the complex conjugate of the denominator to get the denominator into real form. Then compute that denominator value and divide it into the complex number on top.